# Woodworking Plans for an Office Desk

Tags: wooden-furniture, woodworking, planning

I am looking to build a desk for my office (L-shaped), but I am rather new at woodworking.  I have the tools, and this would be a long project, but have no idea where to start.

Are there any good places to buy plans from?  Where should I even start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plansnow.com](http://plansnow.com/) is a great place to look.  The plans are in color, have cutlists and step-by-step instructions.  That's where I started when I built my first shop furniture.  They are plans from the [Woodsmith and ShopNotes](http://www.woodsmith.com/) magazines.